# How to fade in and fade out a label. continuously

Tags: objective-c

In my Xcode project I have put a label on an xib.

I want to fade the label in and out continuously until the user taps the screen. When this happens I want a new view to appear.

Can anyone suggest how to do the fade-in/out?

Comment: just tell us what you have so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could put a pair of chained animation in a loop or call a function that holds the chained animation everytime until you encounter a user tap.

By Chained animation, I mean something like this (You can set the animation duration to suit your needs):

```
myLabel.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     myLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                      [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                            delay:1.0
                                           options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                              animations:^{
                                     myLabel.alpha = 0.0;

                              }  
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
                 }];
```

The above code will first fade in your label and then fade it out. You can put that in a function and call it until you encounter user tap.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of nesting blocks and manually restarting your animations, you can use the option pair `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` to tell Core Animation you want the label to fade in and out continuously.

```
- (void)startAnimatingLabel
{
    self.label.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations:^{
                         self.label.alpha = 1;
                     } completion:nil];
}
```

To stop the animations from running, just remove them from the label's layer.

```
- (IBAction)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [self.label.layer removeAllAnimations];
    self.label.alpha = 0;

    [self presentNewView];
}
```

**EDIT:** A less abrupt way to finish would be to animate from the current view state to the final one (this will interrupt the current, repeating animation).

```
- (IBAction)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         self.label.alpha = 0;
                   } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self presentNewView];
                   }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `CABasicAnimation` and add it to your label:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animation.fromValue = @(1.0f);
animation.toValue = @(0.1f);
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
animation.duration = 0.75;
animation.autoreverses = YES;

[label.layer addAnimation:animation];
```

When you click on your button, just get a pointer to that label and remove all the animations:

```
[label.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it give you the ability to manage the animation repeat count if you replaced **INFINITY** with your repeat count

```
fadingLabel.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fadingLabel" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:4.0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:INFINITY];

fadingLabel.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Wayne Hartman's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17824498/2452039) in Swift 4

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
animation.fromValue = 1
animation.toValue = 0.1
animation.duration = 0.75
animation.repeatCount = .infinity
animation.autoreverses = true
label.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

and

```
label.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```